# Error in ENMeval when running MaxEnt using R studio

Tags: error, maxent, habitat-modeling, rstudio

I have an error in ENMeval when running Maxent using R studio.
"error is Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 12659, 0"
I looked it up and it says it's due to NA data, but I don't know exactly what the problem is.
Please help me

My code ==============================================

> library(ENMeval)
> library(raster)
> occurrences <- read.csv("D:/ENMeval/22.9-23.4.csv")
> env_layers <- stack("D:/ENMeval/test/tif/ANP.tif")
> env_layers <- stack("D:/ENMeval/test/tif/ANT.tif")
> env_layers <- stack("D:/ENMeval/test/tif/Aspect.tif")
> env_layers <- stack("D:/ENMeval/test/tif/DB.tif")
> env_layers <- stack("D:/ENMeval/test/tif/DPPWD.tif")
> env_layers <- stack("D:/ENMeval/test/tif/DR.tif")
> env_layers <- stack("D:/ENMeval/test/tif/DWB.tif")
> env_layers <- stack("D:/ENMeval/test/tif/JP.tif")
> env_layers <- stack("D:/ENMeval/test/tif/MP.tif")
> env_layers <- stack("D:/ENMeval/test/tif/Slope.tif")
> results <- ENMevaluate(occs = occurrences, envs = env_layers, algorithm = "maxent.jar", method = 'block', RMvalues = c(0.5, 1, 2, 3), fc = c("L", "Q", "H"))

- Running ENMeval v2.0.4 with legacy arguments. These will be phased out in the next version. *** Running initial checks... *** * Randomly sampling 10000 background points ... * Removed 4995 occurrence localities that shared the same grid cell. * Clamping predictor variable rasters... * Model evaluations with spatial block (4-fold) cross validation and lat_lon orientation... *** Running ENMeval v2.0.4 with maxent.jar v3.4.3 from dismo package v1.3.14 *** |===== | 8%
  Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 12656, 0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.